# Delaunay plot and Igraph

Tags: python, igraph, delaunay

I have a set of (x,y) coordinates and I want to create a graph (igraph) by using these (x,y) coordinates. First I create the Delaunay triangle from this point then use the "delaunay.simplices" to find edges to use it in igraph. Problem is that my data points are curvey almost on a complete circle (it is the position of retina cells). The problem is when I make the Delaunay plot it connects the points that are far from each other (please see the attached picture). How can I create a Delaunay triangle in a way that just points that are near each other are connected? In other words I need to remove the edges inside of the complete circle (retina).
Data point Sample:

```
[[ -337.97697446,  7540.58307945],
       [-1815.6445473 ,  7056.03016277],
       [ -443.129876  ,   742.95651638],
       [  560.91116647,  8221.13103087],
       [-2043.59680333,  6927.41838391],
       [-3176.31452551,  3346.89857915],
       [ -784.1490326 ,   760.8154378 ],
       [ 5170.40467349,  8136.41340492],
       [ -742.23061811,   799.05871867],
       [ 1462.82113245,   978.95894247],
       [-1874.57436117,  6983.1503229 ],
       [-2310.81830323,  1530.35866448],
       [-2910.71747603,  5246.51145717],
       [ -888.21996994,   798.45066095],
       [ 4498.63094122,  8260.69637833],
       [-2899.33052683,  2130.60899211],
       [-1700.36710286,  7173.3962959 ],
       [-1610.2063535 ,  7214.58267473],
       [ 1378.99115594,  8329.96965215],
       [-3089.39467232,  2513.75733145],
       [-3194.07782921,  3820.99309382],
       [-3209.92285253,  2896.37506385],
       [ 7197.81822286,  5896.18071003],
       [ -450.75080896,  7525.26743227],
       [ -113.62034104,   627.17361551],
       [-3263.17851197,  3425.66085986],
       [ 3692.02214764,  8503.70959198],
       [ 2074.11632568,  8349.8755875 ],
       [ 6015.49872449,  3635.69969512],
       [ 7003.71354705,  6648.72238021],
       [ 6912.25041128,  4732.48378599],
       [ 3171.75729506,  8364.60820082],
       [-2218.36898372,  1409.32375715],
       [ 6695.93283727,  7010.2533557 ],
       [ 2189.84584047,  8368.56645389],
       [ 3406.81534596,  8432.77932065],
       [-2569.97377757,  6210.20316803],
       [ 4238.33917379,  8285.06998187],
       [ 2260.16101844,  8429.82132311],
       [ 3519.53740115,  8291.11207523],
       [ 2682.00418224,  8356.9073382 ],
       [ 3583.38759555,  8341.96511715],
       [-2480.84539734,  6324.03943137],
       [-1608.29692142,  7137.9205374 ],
       [ 4772.58940226,  8312.16759039],
       [  912.35520444,  8313.72411438],
       [ 6951.82432889,  6805.60977411],
       [ 4631.51637666,  8359.21654299],
       [-2960.74382434,  5388.2309139 ],
       [-1554.58457283,  1103.3527351 ]]
```

[image: Delaunay plot]:

Comment: why do you need a Delaunay triangulation, after all? do you want to get a convex hull instead?

Answer (score 1):

calculate the distance matrix, then filter out the dots with shortest distances between each other; can take a while for large datasets (hundreds of dots)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs/), an open-source package for interactive graph visualization in Python. It can recognize graph objects from network analysis libraries like NetworkX, igraph, graph-tool and others.

Here's a solution that uses scipy to calculate a Delaunay triangulation, NetworkX to create a graph and gravis to visualize it. It uses the convex hull from the triangulation to connect the outermost points (red edges), and then the simplices to connect inner points (black edges) but only those that are within a chosen threshold distance that you can vary as needed. I've used the points you've provided in your question.

```
import math

import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx
import scipy.spatial


triangulation = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points)

g = nx.Graph()

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(points):
    g.add_node(i, x=x/10, y=y/10)

for i, j in triangulation.convex_hull:
    g.add_edge(i, j, color='red', size=2)

threshold = 2000
for i, j, k in triangulation.simplices:
    for a, b in [(i, j), (j, k), (k, i)]:
        p1 = points[a]
        p2 = points[b]
        distance = math.dist(p1, p2)
        if distance < threshold:
            g.add_edge(a, b)
    
gv.d3(g)
```

Result in a Jupyter notebook:
[Graph visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJgyZ.png)